# How to solve a linear system with cholesky decomposition with sparse matrix in Python?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, theano

I have a sparse matrix and i performed Cholesky decomposition with Theano with this line:

```
theano.tensor.slinalg.Cholesky(lower=True)
```

where it said it worked and showed this:

```
Cholesky{lower=<32x32 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 154 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, destructive=False, on_error='raise'}
```

How should i solve the system and find `x`? I tried with `theano.tensor.slinalg.Solve` but it returns this:

```
Solve{A_structure='general', lower=False, overwrite_A=False, overwrite_b=False}
```